# Scrolling within a div, do not affect main scrollbar?

Tags: html

I have a div with a vertical scrollbar, with a main window scrollbar. when i'm scrolling within the div, and it reaches the end of the scroll, it will then affect the main scroll bar.

Is is possible to set any scrolls within the div to not affect the main scroll bar?

Oh, and the best part is that, i'm using facebook canvas, which mean i have no access to the main scrollbar.

Comment: No, it is not possible for the content of an iframe to effect the parent of that iframe.

Comment: i was thinking to disable scrollbar after it reaches the end of the div scroll, this way i no need to mess with anything out of the iframe?

Comment: You can't modify the parent iframe.  If, within your document, you have a div you can manipulate, you can use `overflow-y: hidden` in css to disable the scroll bar _of that div_.